# osx - writing a script in terminal to move files from a parent folder to different sub folders

Tags: macos, bash, file

I have a folder that includes music files named with `a number + a space + the band's name + space + a dash + space + the song name`.

I want to do a task that seems simple to write in a script, but I don't know the commands to do so : if a filename has that pattern, I want to move it to a folder named as the band name.

Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: And what happens when the band's name has a space in it?

Comment: I don't know if that's usable in bash scripts, but with regular expressions, if i recall correctly, you can just search the part between the number and the dash and then remove the first and last character.

Comment: It'd be something like that : `if [[ "$filename" =~ "^[0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+ - [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+" ]]
then
    mv ./$filename ./GETBANDNAME/$filename
fi`, the problem being : how do i use this on all the files in one given folder and how i get the band name.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i use this on all the files in one given folder and how i get
>   the band name.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for filename in [0-9]*\ *\ -\ *
do  echo "$filename"
    bandname=${filename#* }     # remove number + space
    bandname=${bandname% - *}   # remove space + dash + space + song name
    mkdir -p "$bandname"
    mv -n "$filename" "$bandname"
done
```